# What does a "stray evidence" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, expressions

In the following paragraph:

> This plot is a stray evidence of how Pearson correlation coefficient is often incomputable and hence ineffective.

What does the expression *"a stray evidence"* mean?

Could you give some more examples?

Comment: "Evidence" is a mass noun, and doesn't take the indefinite article or number adjectives. If you want to specify just one, you say "a stray **piece** of evidence".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*A stray evidence* refers to a piece of evidence that wasn't necessarily tied closely in to the subject.  One of Dictionary.com's definitions of *[stray](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stray)* is:

> **10.** found or occurring apart from others or as an isolated or casual instance; incidental or occasional.

Comment: I'm afraid there aren't many examples for OP. Google finds 23 hits in total for *a stray evidence*, which net down to six distinct instances of a usage like OP's. Without the article, *stray evidence* scores a slightly more respectable 1000 or so. Not exactly commonplace, but enough to back me up in thinking this use of the article is a bit odd here.

Comment: "Evidence" is a mass noun, and doesn't take the indefinite article or number adjectives. If you want to specify just one, you say "a stray **piece** of evidence".